# Merge 3 images to one PDF file in Oracle APEX using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, jspdf

I am trying to merge 3 images to one PDF file using jsPDF in Oracle APEX. Following code works fine but somehow it does not append 3rd image (item name - P29_NEW_1_1)  to file PDF file. Also i am looking for way to save final PDF to DB using apex.server.process.

1. Final PDF does not have 3rd image
2. How to save final PDF to Oracle DB using apex.server.process.

Below is JavaScript code i am using -

```
// Function to handle file uploads and PDF creation
function handleFileUpload() {
    var itemNames = ['P29_NEW', 'P29_NEW_1', 'P29_NEW_1_1'];
    var selectedFiles = [];
    var imgToPdf = new jsPDF();
    var validationPassed = true; // Flag to track validation status

    // Iterate through file inputs and perform validations
    itemNames.forEach(function(itemName) {
        var fileInput = $x(itemName);

        if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];

            // Check file size
            if (file.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
                alert('File size exceeds 5MB limit.');
                validationPassed = false;
                return;
            }

            // Check file type
            var fileType = getFileExtension(file.name);
            if (fileType !== 'JPEG' && fileType !== 'JPG' && fileType !== 'PNG') {
                alert('Please upload images in JPEG, JPG, or PNG format.');
                validationPassed = false;
                return;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                selectedFiles.push({
                    name: file.name,
                    data: e.target.result,
                    type: fileType
                });
                
            if (selectedFiles.length === 3) {
                alert('selectedFiles.length:'+selectedFiles.length);
                selectedFiles.forEach(function(file) {
                    imgToPdf.addImage(file.data, file.type, 20, 10, 150, 200);
                    imgToPdf.addPage();
                });

                // Remove the last extra page added by addPage()
                imgToPdf.deletePage(selectedFiles.length);

                // Save the PDF content as a binary string
                var pdfContent = imgToPdf.output('blob');

                // Download the PDF in the browser
                imgToPdf.save('merged_images.pdf');

                // Send the PDF content to the server to save in DB
                //savePdfToDB(pdfContent);
            }    
                
            };
                       
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            alert('Please select a file.');
            validationPassed = false;
        }
    });

    // If validation passed, proceed with PDF creation
    
}

// Function to get file extension
function getFileExtension(filename) {
    return filename.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();
}

handleFileUpload();
```

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with your jsPDF issue - the counting of the pages start from 1, not from 0. When you delete the page with the method .deletePage you are passing selectedFiles.length, which in this code is 3. In that moment you have pdf file with 1, 2 and 3 page with images and 4 without. When you delete 3 with image, you have 1 and 2 with image, and 3 which was previous 4 without image. You have to write imgToPdf.deletePage(selectedFiles.length + 1);.